# Pattern match map on materialized observable

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Say I want to convert an `Observable[T]` into an `Observable[Try[T]]`. I wanted to pattern-match over the materialized original observable, but I don't know what to return for `OnCompleted()`:

```
obs.materialized map {
  case OnNext(v) => Success(v)
  case OnError(t) => Failure(t)
  case OnCompleted() => // What do I return here?
}
```

- in general I don't understand how I can map on materialized observables when `OnCompleted` is a case that doesn't actually correspond to an "element" of the observable.

Answer (score 2):

[In Rx Java materialized Observable is a list of notifications](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Observable-Utility-Operators) - and `OnCompleted`/`OnError` is  the last and only one notification. Same for RxScala i think. Threating each message as `Success` seems to be incorrect - because last `Success`/`Failure` is success/failure for **whole sequence**, so it's better to use `Try` for `OnError`/`OnCompleted` message only (but it will be `Observable[T] => Observable[Msg[T]]`):

```
trait Msg[T]
case class Data[T](d: T) extends Msg[T]
case class End[T](t: Try[Observable[T]]) extends Msg[T]
obs.materialize map {
  case OnNext(v) => Data(v)
  case OnError(t) => End(Failure(t))
  case OnCompleted() => End(Success(obs))
}
```

Anyway, you can't (from logical perspective) convert `Observable[T]` into `Observable[Try[T]]` until last notification is received, so actually you can convert it only into `Future[Observable[Try[T]]` or just `Future[Observable[T]]` (because `Observable` completes or fails for all its elements):

```
 val p = promise[Observable[Notification[T]]]

 obs.materialize flatMap {
  case OnNext(v) => Some(v)
  case OnError(t) =>  p.fail(t); None
  case OnCompleted() => p.complete(obs); None
 }

 p.future
```

Keep in mind that every map-like operation on this future will be applied after all notifications received (like `doOnTerminate`).